# Spread our elements over parent width

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to spread out 3 elements over the width of the screen. I've tried different methods but when I use `inline-block` the second element doesn't center. When I leave out `inline-block` the third element shows on the next line. Any suggestions?

```html
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        * {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }
        .base {
            display: block;
            height: 200px;
            background-color: #eeeeee;
        }
        .container {
        }
        .shape {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            background-color: #ff0000;
        }
        .container {
        }
        #left {
            float: left;
        }
        #center {
            margin: auto;
        }
        #right {
            float: right;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="base">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="shape" id="left"></div>
            <div class="shape" id="center"></div>
            <div class="shape" id="right"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to use [display:flex;](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/flex)

```html
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .base {
          
            height: 200px;
            background-color: #eeeeee;
            display:flex;
            justify-content:space-between;
           
        }

        .shape {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            background-color: #ff0000;
             align-self: flex-end;
        }
 
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="base">

            <div class="shape" id="left"></div>
            <div class="shape" id="center"></div>
            <div class="shape" id="right"></div>
        
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked and the code is also much cleaner like this. How would you go about aligning the blocks to the bottom of the gray parent? When I change the container position to absolute and set bottom to 0, it messes up the layout again.

Comment: @devDesigner i have updated my answer please check now.

Comment: Thanks Dinesh, you're the best!

Comment: @devDesigner You are welcome. please accept the answer, if it helped your, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below CSS3 to do this.

```css
* {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }
        .base {
            display: block;
            height: 200px;
            background-color: #eeeeee;
        }
        .container {
        }
        .shape {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            background-color: #ff0000;
        }
        .container {
        display:flex;
        justify-content:space-between;
        }
```

```html
<div class="base">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="shape" id="left"></div>
            <div class="shape" id="center"></div>
            <div class="shape" id="right"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS Solution

```css
* {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }
        .base {
            display: block;
            height: 200px;
            background-color: #eeeeee;
        }
        .container {
        }
        .shape {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            background-color: #ff0000;
        }
        .container {
          display:block;
          text-align:center;
        }
        #left{
          float:left;
        }
        #right{
          float:right;
        }
        #center{
          display:inline-block;
        }
```

```html
<div class="base">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="shape" id="left"></div>
            <div class="shape" id="center"></div>
            <div class="shape" id="right"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it!

Comment: How can you do it with CSS (no CSS3) though?

Comment: @dabadaba check my CSS solution